# loop through folders and remove file

Tags: bash

I have the code below. If I want to loop through PKA1 through PKA24, how do i do that, without manually typing it all out

```
 cd PKA1/1keV/
    rm cascade.dump
 cd ../../
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider using something like this

```
rm PKA{1..24}/1keV/cascade.dump
```

Comment: This is OK as long as you are using `bash`.

Comment: @Bob it's tagged [tag:bash]

Comment: Good point! I always tend to go for more generic answers, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you don't have to *be* in a directory to remove the file, so you could just say:

```
rm PKA1/1keV/cascade.dump
rm PKA2/1keV/cascade.dump
```

etc. However, a loop can be used:

```
for i in $(seq 24); do
   rm PKA$i/1keV/cascade.dump
done
```

(the `seq` command generates the number 1 to 24 automatically)

Comment: Or just `rm PKA{1..24}/1keV/cascade.dump`.  or `find . -name cascade.dump -type f -delete`.

Comment: The comment about `bash` also applies here. The `find` solution is a bit dangerous, as there might be other subdirectories containing `cascade.dump` that you don't want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

'find' is your answer:

First use it with 'echo' to check out that everything will work correctly.
I suppose that you don't care about the same filename in more PKA directories.

```
find PKA* -name "cascade.dump" -exec rm {} \;
```

Otherwise you have to fix the first pattern.

Comment: That will also hit directories such as `PKA99` (if it exists) whereas the OP as specified only `PKA1`..`PKA24`. Your `-exec rm{} \;` kicks off an instance of `rm` for every file. While there are only 24 it's not a big deal but for a large number it files it could be. You'd be better with `-delete` if it exists for your `find` version, which doesn't fork any separate processes.

Comment: You are true. I warned him about more directories. Because he told about a dump file I supposed that he has more and he does not care; also I mention this.